# twitter bootstrap image slider not going below header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need some help with a image slider that is not playing well with my code for some reason every time I add an image slider to my website it just does not want to work the way I hope as you can see from the code snippet I would like to add the slider under the header tags and before the nav but every time I add the slider it just keeps trying to overlap the header for some reason and the images wont show up on the slider they will just keep going to the side of the slider for some unknown reason.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans);
 body {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}
.atag {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
}
header[role="banner"] #logo-main {
  display: block;
}
header {
  background-color: red;
}
/*----Nav bar color change----*/

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ff2424;
  border-color: #e82c2c;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #bdbdbd;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #bdbdbd;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #bdbdbd;
  background-color: #e82c2c;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #bdbdbd;
  background-color: #e82c2c;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #e82c2c;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #e82c2c;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #bdbdbd;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #bdbdbd;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #bdbdbd;
    background-color: #e82c2c;
  }
}
/*---- End of Nav bar color change----*/

#footer {
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Welcome</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS CDN -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- jQuery Mobile -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">

  <!-- Custom Fonts -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<header class="col-lg-12" role="banner">
  <img id="logo-main" src="img/logo.png" width="300" alt="Main Logo">
</header>

<body>
  <div>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->

      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="img/image1.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="First slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Slide 1</h1>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/400/people" style="width:100%" data-src="" alt="Second    slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Slide 2</h1>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/400/abstract" style="width:100%" data-src="" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Slide 3</h1>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-default">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#.html">Buildings</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#.html">History</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#.html">Businesses</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#.html">Location</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#.html">People</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    <!-- /.container -->
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I answered the question correctly with how you're asking,

I gave your `<header>` a height for demo purposes, and put it inside your `<body>` tag, you had it outside of it. But it's working now demo on bottom.

```
<body>
   <header class="col-lg-12" role="banner">
      <img id="logo-main" src="img/logo.png" width="300" alt="Main Logo">
    </header>
  <div>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->

      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="img/image1.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="First slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Slide 1</h1>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/400/people" style="width:100%" data-src="" alt="Second    slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Slide 2</h1>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/400/abstract" style="width:100%" data-src="" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Slide 3</h1>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-default">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#.html">Buildings</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#.html">History</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#.html">Businesses</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#.html">Location</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#.html">People</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    <!-- /.container -->
  </nav>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans);
 body {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}
.atag {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
header{
   height: 30px;
}
/*----Nav bar color change----*/

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ff2424;
  border-color: #e82c2c;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #bdbdbd;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #bdbdbd;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #bdbdbd;
  background-color: #e82c2c;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #bdbdbd;
  background-color: #e82c2c;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #e82c2c;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #e82c2c;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #bdbdbd;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #bdbdbd;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #bdbdbd;
    background-color: #e82c2c;
  }
}
/*---- End of Nav bar color change----*/

#footer {
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/jbpweG/?editors=110)